# Modify style of 'Pay with Card' Stripe button

Tags: css, stripe-payments

Is it possible to modify style of "Pay with Card" Stripe button? I've tried modifying by,

- adding a new class defined in external style sheet
- modifying its own class of `stripe-button` in external style sheet
- and editing it inline with `style=""`

But I cannot get the button to change its style.

It looks like it might be possible with the `custom integration` instead of the `simple integration` (source: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple), but I was hoping there was something simpler.

**Button with default style:**

[image]

Does anyone have experience with this?

(I'm integrating into Ruby on Rails if that makes any difference.)

Comment: What's the problem with `custom integration`? You can use your own button style and separate the logic. It doesn't seem to be so complicated ;)

Comment: You're right. It wasn't thaaat complicated.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/u01jmg3/a9f53d4c4978c76a87f433570af4bbbc

Comment: Stripe offers `data-label` for this button https://stackoverflow.com/a/54894894/1536309

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Search for this **class**:

```
.stripe-button-el span
```

I think this is where you have to modify your own button's style. 
You may overwrite it within your own external css file.

Comment: Note that Stripe does not guarantee the structure of the button and thus it can change at any time.

Comment: Marking this as correct because I asked how to edit the button, but the superior solution in the end was to use `custom integration`

Answer (score 42):

None of those worked for me. I ended up hiding the button in javascript and making a new one.

```
<form action="/your-server-side-code" method="POST">
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="xxx"
        data-amount="999"
        data-name="zzz"         
        data-locale="auto">
    </script>
    <script>
        // Hide default stripe button, be careful there if you
        // have more than 1 button of that class
        document.getElementsByClassName("stripe-button-el")[0].style.display = 'none';
    </script>
    <button type="submit" class="yourCustomClass">Buy my things</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Not the most elegant solution, but does the job. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: Worked like a charm. :D

Answer (score 10):

Although a little hacky, for anyone wanting a super quick and simple way of using a different button along with the "simple integration", especially if you don't have "solid JavaScript skills", you can just hide the Stripe button with;

```
.stripe-button-el { display: none }
```

This way, any submit button within the form will call the checkout so you can just use the button you already had before introducing Stripe.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I tried this, and Stripe's default styles were overriding my CSS. So then I wrote `.stripeFormContainer .stripe-button-el` (because my form happens to be enclosed in a div with class `stripeFormContainer `), and it worked! I now use a button from Bootstrap like this: `<button class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Reserve My Spot</button>`.

Comment: Just a heads up with this method, the submit button gets disabled when clicked but is **not** re-enabled if the user closes the Checkout prompt, unlike the default Stripe button which *is* re-enabled. An unfortunate UX bug with this approach.

Comment: I made mine force it because it was working with just this. My CSS for this button looks like `.stripe-button-el { display: none !important; } `

Answer (score 8):

The following will override the background color with the custom color `#EB649C`. Disabling the background-image is required, as well as styling both the button and it's inside span tag.

```
button.stripe-button-el,
button.stripe-button-el>span {
  background-color: #EB649C !important;
  background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use **data-label** its part of the regular stripe Checkout API:

```
<script
  src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
  data-key="<%= ENV.fetch('STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY') %>"
  data-amount="10000"
  data-label="Proceed to Pay with Card"
  ...
  ...
  data-locale="auto">
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery, you can also simply scale the button like this:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".stripe-button-el").css({'transform': 'scale(2)'});
  });
</script>
```

Or replace it by a button with any image you want, like this:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".stripe-button-el").replaceWith('<button type="submit" class="pay"><img src="/assets/paywithcard.jpg"></button>');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Scaling seems to work well for me. Though 2x was a bit excessive for my purpose. Used 1.5x instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the button styles with Jquery and add your own. Worked a charm for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".stripe-button-el span").remove();
            $("button.stripe-button-el").removeAttr('style').css({
                "display":"inline-block",
                "width":"100%",
                "padding":"15px",
                "background":"#3fb0ac",
                "color":"white",
                "font-size":"1.3em" }).html("Sign Me Up!");
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.stripe-button-el` span actually works.

But you need to add `!important` in CSS to overwrite the default CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
$(".stripe-button-el").find("span").remove();
$(".stripe-button-el").html("Proceed to pay");
```

Pay with card is inside a span.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who want to change the background color of the button, make sure you do something like

```
.stripe-button-el span {
  background: #5e366a !important;
  background-image:none !important;
  background-color: #5e366a !important;
}
```

in your css file. this will change the actual background of the button fr you. If you wish to have the parent div changed, you can do the same thing without the span or do a direct inline style.